# Unable to install windows subsystem for linux, error 0x800f0831

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I tried to install wsl without enabling it, it gives me this error

```bsh
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install
wsl : The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ wsl --install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

After trying out Microsoft's [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) to manual installation, it still fails

```bsh
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19043.1081

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0831

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

When I tried to enable wsl via command prompt, it gives the same error. It "trys" to search/enable/install for wsl but in the end, it gives the same error code (same in title).

- Is my computer capable of this virtualization?
- Do I need to update something?
- Have I messed up anything in the system files?

Comment: “Do I need to update something?” - Try performing an in-place repair install. Download a copy of Windows 10 21H2 ISO, and install Windows from within Windows, and choose the option that keeps everything. If it still doesn’t successfully install provide the log file

Comment: where do I find the log files, if it doesn't fix? I haven't tried it yet. @Ramhound

Comment: @Ramhound is there a risk of losing my files?